# Trajectory of a particle performing projectile after vertical circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Let us suppose that at the bottom of the vertical circle, a particle initially at rest and tied to a string with one end fixed at the origin $O$, is given a velocity $v$ (with $\sqrt{2gR}<v<\sqrt{5gR}$) and the particle proceeds to continue in a circular path of radius $R$ until its tension becomes $0$. That point will obviously be somewhere in the upper right quadrant. So, my question here is, what will be the angle of the projectile from horizontal at the point where the string slackens? Will that angle be equal to the angle made by the string with the vertical when it slacks?